# Will Software Upgrade wipe data

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, ota-update, motorola-moto-e

I have a Motorola E2. I am considering the Marshmallow system update,  but I have a few questions to ask (the system update is officially offered by motorola).

Questions

1. Lets say I rooted my phone and made a normal app into a system app, will the upgrade wipe the system app.
2. Will the latest version of all Google apps be flashed.
3. I have an issue ever since unrooting where I cannot log into Google account. Will the upgrade be likely to fix this issue.

Any anwsers will be well appreciated.

Comment: You cannot have OEM update till you revert to stock

Comment: Right. So the update will not work in the first place?

Comment: And will flashing stock ROM remove a system app that I have created?

Comment: Yes. When you revert to stock, your system app created by you will vanish, and whatever Google apps come with upgrade will be flashed. Regarding root, which root do you have? Normal or systemless, which version of su?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are rooted, you will not have any chance to get OTA updates. Only after complete unroot or reset makes device Official again.

1. You are required to do the process again(to make user app as system app).
2. Google apps for that android version will be provided by the manufacturer(Motorola).
3. Simply unrooting won't make it official again. That's why you have got some problems on Google account

Comment: OK. So assuming I go back to Stock ROM... I will have to redo the system app; my google apps will be updated; and I will be able to use google account?

Comment: Not to forget locking boot loader

Comment: OK. Right now my phone is only unrooted. Do I have to lock bootloader only, or first Stock then bootloader lock?

Comment: Backup is important. fistly lock bootloader.

Comment: OK. So backup then lock bootloader and then update system and everything will be fine?

Comment: Sorry for so many questions, I just do not want anything going wrong.

Comment: Do backup, then lock bootloader, after that check for update, if available, update it. Otherwise, you need to flash Stock ROM and then check for update.